# Approaches for populating Java objects from maps

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, deserialization

I'm dealing with a recurring pattern at work.

```
public class SapExample
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // read SAP data..

    // get table
    List<Map<String, Object>> objects = getTable("ET_WIDGET");

    for (Map<String, Object> entry : objects)
    {
      Object value = entry.get("WDGT_ID");
      String id = (value != null) ? String.valueOf(value) : ""; // or null

      value = entry.get("WDGT_NAME");
      String name = (value != null) ? String.valueOf(value) : ""; // or null

      value = entry.get("WDGT_DESC");
      String description = (value != null) ? String.valueOf(value) : ""; // or null

      // create object from data
      //Widget obj = new Widget(id, name, description);
    }
  }

  private static List<Map<String, Object>> getTable(String string)
  {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

<sub>Easy example with no relations between objects. More complex scenarios, where class A has a member of class B do also occur and are solved with use of foreign keys.</sub>

Tables returned from the database
are handled as `List<Map<String, Object>>`, where `Map<String, Object>` depicts a row in given table that maps the column names to values of type `Object`, which internally mostly are of type `String` or `Date`.

The map contains the data needed to initialize objects of a certain type, which depends on the current table. I **can't** change that.

Programmers directly or indirectly access the data in the way I showed above and create instances of the desired objects.

---

I find that a very verbose and unesthetic way of programming.

Is it possible to utilize JAXB or other technologies to solve this problem in a declarative way (e.g. by use of XML)?
If it is possible to use JAXB, what do I have to do? I suppose I have to override some classes.

Comment: Is your data stored as XML? If so, then yes, you can use an XML parser like DOM or SAX or JAXB.

Comment: The data is stored as `List<Map<String, Object>>` as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. JAXB is specifically used for XML binding (Java<->XML). I don't see any XML in your question so I don't understand why you mention this. Is your problem about 1) Database <-> Java Object mapping? 2) Initializing default values? 3) Serialization?

Comment: Can you not simply use Hibernate or another ORM?

Comment: It's about database mapping (SAP) in a declarative way (e.g. by use of XML). I'm thinking about creating an object model that can be described in a declarative way and helps me to create objects out of tables in form of `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

Comment: @mike Your question also mentions JAXB, which only makes sense if your data is stored as XML. As of right now your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @rghome I don't think so. I can't change so whole architecture of the company I work for.

Comment: @KevinWorkman JAXB serializes XMLs into java objects. My idea is to use JAXB to serialize `Map<String, Object>` into an instance of the desired class.

Comment: @mike And that doesn't make any sense, unless your data is stored as XML.

Comment: Maybe my wording is wrong, or maybe JAXB cannot be extend to behave like that. But do you understand what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Using JAXB to serialize a Map into in instance of a class is not a good idea to me because, JAXB is meant to handle XML, and what you try to acheive is map from Map to an instance of another object. Maybe you could use your own set of annotations and have a factory that can take the map as input an create the instance of the object based on these annotations

Comment: **Reuse** is one of the reasons behind OOP. Of course JAXB is not meant for that, but why should I start from scratch. This is why I am searching for already existing solutions, that I can apply to my problem. It does not have to be JAXB, it was just the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*JAXB* seems to be inappropriate for your case because it is meant to handle XML and your problem doesn't involve XML.

As an alternative you could use annotations and reflection:

#### Create your own annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Mapped {
    String value() default "";
    String defaultValue() default "";
}
```

#### Annotate your Widget/POJO:

```
public class Widget {
    @Mapped(key = "WDGT_ID", defaultValue = "")
    private String id;
    @Mapped(key = "WDGT_NAME", defaultValue = "")
    private String name;
    @Mapped(key = "WDGT_DESC", defaultValue = "")
    private String description;

    [constructors...]
    [getters&setters...]
}
```

#### Implement a "*factory/builder*" method that can create your POJO:

```
public T getObject(Map<String, Object> source, Class<T> clazz) {
    [some java introspection code]
}
```

#### Your code would become:

```
public class SapExample
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // read SAP data..

    // get table
    List<Map<String, Object>> objects = getTable("ET_WIDGET");

    for (Map<String, Object> entry : objects) {
        Widget obj = getObject(entry , Widget.class);
    }
  }

  private static List<Map<String, Object>> getTable(String string)
  {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

The difficult part here is the "*factory*" method. I will not provide the code here because it requires a lot of time to produce and the implementation can depend on your context. But I hope you have understood the idea.

Comment: How would you handle dependencies between classes, i.e. if `Widget` had a member of type `Foo`, whose data resides in table `ET_FOO`?

Comment: Choose: 1) Do nothing and use the id by itseld. 2) Implement it in the `getObject` method, but honestly 3) Use JPA (any ORM based solution). I understand you may not be allowed to do this, but doing this in 2 may lead to you (re-)implement JPA by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

First thing - forget about XML, because it has nothing particular to do with what you want to do.

What you want is to take data in a `Map` and copy it into a normal object. There is a class that can do that in the Apache BeanUtils library - `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap`.

There are some preconditions: your target classes must be bean-type objects - in other words they must have putlic getters and setters.

You can then wrap one of these in a BeanMap as follows:

```
BeanMap beanMap = new BeanMap(myObject)
```

then set the fields in the object:

```
beanMap.put(fieldName, value)
```

So you can see that you can use the column-names of the entries in your input map to set the fields in the target object. The problem is that the column-names are not exactly the same as the field-names, so you will have to have some sort of mapping function. I would propose you do that either by creating a mapping in Java:

```
someMap.put("ET_WIDGET.WIDGET_ID", "ID")
```

Or you use a property file.

You can create the object itself using the `Class.newInstance` method and have a mapping of table name to class name in a similar way to above.

Comment: That looks interesting. ...XML could be used for the mapping data.

Comment: If you really want to use XML for something and you don't care what (don't worry - you are not alone there), yes you can, but it will probably take you a lot longer than just using a property file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As @superbob said, using JPA or some other OR mapper really really would be a more concise and cleaner approach. But I'll consider all answers here, if I have to write my own solution.